# Confused about the definition of the Kahn-Priddy map

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, adjoint-functors, mapping-space

The Kahn-Priddy map is defined in various papers as follows:

Define $i:\mathbb {RP}^{n-1}\rightarrow O(n)$ by taking $\ell\in \mathbb {RP}^{n-1}$ to the reflection across $\ell^\perp.$ Define $j:O(n)\rightarrow \Omega^nS^n$ by identifying $S^n=\mathbb R^n\cup \{\infty\}$ with basepoint $\infty$, and extending the orthogonal self-maps of $\mathbb R^n$ to this one-point compactification. Then the Kahn-Priddy map $\lambda:\Sigma^n\mathbb {RP}^{n-1}\rightarrow S^n$ is the adjoint of $j\circ i:\mathbb {RP}^{n-1}\rightarrow \Omega^nS^n$.

This uses the pointed mapping adjunction $$\text{Map}_*(\Sigma^n \mathbb {RP}^{n-1},S^n)=\text{Map}_*(S^n\wedge \mathbb {RP}^{n-1},S^n)=\text{Map}_*\big(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1},\text{Map}_*(S^n,S^n)\big)=\text{Map}_*\big(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1},\Omega^nS^n\big)$$
However, for any $\ell\in \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$, the map $j\circ i(\ell)\in \Omega^nS^n$ has degree $-1$ and thus cannot be homotoped to a constant map, one of which is the natural choice of base-point in $\Omega^nS^n$.

In some other papers, I have seen this discussed in terms of a map $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}\rightarrow SO(n)$ (not explicitly defined, just attributed to either Hopf or James). This makes me think that the appropriate map to define $\lambda$ needs to be modified from $j\circ i$, and the obvious choice seems to be "pick a basepoint $\ell_{\!0}\in \mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ and compose each map with $i(\ell_{\!0})$."

But I don't know if that's correct, particularly because I don't understand a lot of the algebraic topology that goes into the Kahn-Priddy theorem. In fact, I just want to understand this map to describe the symmetric square of $S^n$ (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384870/the-symmetric-square-of-a-sphere/384890#384890)), but I want to make sure that I'm actually using the correct map. Technically, the description of $\text{Sym}^2(S^n)$ uses a map from the unreduced suspension, which may be easier to define. But I would still like to see what I'm missing in the definition of the Kahn-Priddy map as well.

Comment: Point in $\Bbb R P^n$ corresponds to a reflection in $O(n)$, which in turn defines a degree $-1$ selfmap of $S^n$. Now you need to take any fixed degree $1$ map (for example, identity) and sum of this two maps now has degree $0$ and lands in $\Omega^n S^n$ with proper basepoint.

Comment: Adding to @DenisT. 's comment, all components of ΩnSn are homotopy equivalent (homeomorphic ?) to each other, so it really doesn't make much difference if you translate elements in one component to another (as long as you use the same translation for all elements).